# XDocument.ToString() throwing "' ', hexadecimal value 0x13, is an invalid character." exception

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, silverlight

I want to store XDocument into the SQLXML Datatype. I went through [this Link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/ac074ccb-1a52-4bda-a032-c874d3ba8ce5/) for storing XDOcument into the SQL DB. As per the link while Converting XDocumentObj.ToString() its throwing `"' ', hexadecimal value 0x13, is an invalid character."` exception. Can anyone please help me to fix the problem. How do I store the complete XML file into the database of type XML.

Answer (score 2):

Somehow you got the character U+0013 in there, which is a control character for pausing transmission on serial datalinks. It's unlikely you actually want that, so the real issue isn't that there's a character that's invalid in XML in there, but that there's a character that just shouldn't be there, in there. So find out how it got in there, as that were the real bug is. I'd start by trapping whatever calls add to the document, and throwing when you find a string containing U+0013

Comment: do we have any logic or concept or predefined mechanism something to find them all and ignore all the invalid characters?

Comment: You could just replace them all with nothing. I'd strongly recommend against that unless you know why they are getting in there; it's like necking painkillers because you're in pain instead of going to the doctor and finding out if you've a mild infection that can be cleared up or a 1st stage cancer that'll kill you if you don't get it fixed.

Comment: The xml Document Which I am getting is created by one of a third party library and it contains some characters to represent pixel information, Image data as well as with some other random data which I need to keep it there in that xml document so I can not remove them also. What I can do is, I can ignore them all and store and retrieve the file to or from the SQL DB as it is. Can you please help me to do so.

Comment: Ick! Is this XML1.1? If it's 1.0 you might find further problems, because if you've someone sending you invalid XML (and XML1.0 containing U+0013 is not valid), a lot of bets are off if you try to use XML tools with it. With XML1.1 you can't use that char directly, but you can use it escaped as `&#x13;` (if they use codepoints that are non-chars or unpaired surrogates, or arbitrary bytes that aren't decodable then even that won't work because it's not even valid text). I don't know what XDocument support for XML1.1 is like. In any case, this isn't a valid XML1.0 document, and I'd need to know

Comment: ... more about just what sort of document it actually is, and what you need to preserve from it to have a clear idea of what to do about it. If a replacing approach is going to work, you'll probably want to do it before you load it into the XDocument.

Comment: XDocument declaration says it's xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" and standalone="yes". Now my objective is to store the whole content of the XDocument into the SQL DB as it is and later I'll retrieve it from the DB and fetch only the required information for my module. Any alternate option or way is also fine for me

Comment: If it says that, and contains &#x13; (or if it says anything and contains the octet 0x13 directly), then its buggy XML. If you can't get the third-party to send you real XML, then you're going to have to work out how to separate out the wheat from the chaff first, before you try to use XML tools on it. Just how to do that depends on the bugs in what they send you. If the invalid stuff is restricted to certain elements, you could clear those elements on a text-based pass, for example.